# Validating Phone Number based on country code

Tags: javascript, validation, phone-number

How to validate phone numbers based on country codes in Javascript.

For Example: India-starts with `91-xxxxxxxxxx`, `UK-44-xxxxxxxxxx`, `SZ-268-22xxxxxx` and so on. Like this it should validate other countries country code with phone number which I will enter.

Below is the code which I tried but it is only for one country. Parallelly how to do validate with other countries country code.

```
function validateMobNo(mobno){
var mobno2;
var flag=false;
var mlen= mobno.length;
//alert(mobno.substr(3,mobno.length-3));
if(mobno.charAt(0)!='+' && mlen==10){
    mobno2="+91-"+mobno;
    alert("1>>your mobile wants to be in "+mobno2);
    flag=true;
}
else if(mobno.charAt(0)=='+'){
    if(mobno.substr(0,3)=='+91' && mobno.length==13){
        mobno2=mobno.substr(0,3)+"-"+mobno.substr(3,mobno.length-3);
        alert("2>>your mobile wants to be in "+mobno2);
        flag=true;      
    }
}
else if(mobno.indexOf("-")<0&&mobno.length==12 && mobno.substr(0,2)=='91'){
    mobno2=mobno.substr(0,2)+"-"+mobno.substr(3,mobno.length-2);
    alert("3>>your mobile wants to be in "+mobno2);
    flag=true;
    }
else
    alert("Please correct your mobile No");
if(flag==true)
   document.mobvalidate.mobno.value=mobno2;
else
    document.mobvalidate.mobno.focus()
return flag;

}
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to have an object which contains all the regex patterns to test the various different countries' phone number formats, keyed by the country code. Using string manipulation for this is going to make it a lot more complicated, and more brittle, than it needs to be

Comment: Someones already done the hard work for you this [int-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) jQuery plugin would do the trick.

Comment: I have used this library in the past.  It is well documented.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `some` method to loop over each country code and evaluates with regular erxpressions:

```js
country_codes=['91-', 'UK-44-', 'SZ-268-22']
phone="91-123456789";

is_valid_number = country_codes.some(elem => phone.match('^' + elem));
console.log(is_valid_number );
```

Comment: Exactly am looking for code something like this. Thank you